# NPM global packages unmet dependency

Tags: node.js, npm

I have npm installed on my Windows 8.1 pc.

I am using the following console command to list the global packages I have installed:

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

I then get all packages listed, as follows:

```
C:\Users\usernamehere\AppData\Roaming\npm
├── bower@1.4.1
├── git@0.1.5
├── grunt@0.4.5
├── gulp@3.9.0
├── nodemon@1.3.7
├── npm@2.13.0
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY npm-debug.log@*
└── yo@1.4.6
```

What does the UNMET DEPENDENCY npm-debug.log@* mean, and how do I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I've never seen an `npm-debug.log` npm module, and searching for it using npm search returns no results. Try uninstalling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any regular file that ends up in your global npm/node_modules directory is mistakenly assumed to be a module, and will yield said error.

Demo:

```
$ touch /usr/local/lib/node_modules/zzzfoobar
$ npm list -g --depth=0 | grep zzzfoo
└── UNMET DEPENDENCY zzzfoobar@*
```

If you remove `C:\Users\usernamehere\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm-debug.log` (which you can safely do), it won't be shown anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The `UNMET DEPENDENCY` error occurs when your module is dependent on another module, and this other module is present but has different version.